# How to extend data (interpolation?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extend columns in data frames to match the longest column's length by interpolating(? is that right?) data in between.

I am unfamiliar with the correct terms, so please correct my vocabulary or inform me of how to communicate this better. I believe `pd.DataFrame.resample()` is the answer, but after reviewing the documentation thoroughly I haven't ascertained how to 'extend' a column quite yet.

I have a data frame like this:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0  0    0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1  1    3
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2  2    5
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3  3    3
2000-01-01 00:04:00    4  nan  nan
2000-01-01 00:05:00    5  nan  nan
2000-01-01 00:06:00    6  nan  nan
```

I want to 'extend' the second column so that it is just as long in time but doesn't lose any of its data. After performing the desired method I hope the data would look like this:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0  0    0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1  0.5  1.5
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2  1    3
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3  1.5  4
2000-01-01 00:04:00    4  2    5
2000-01-01 00:05:00    5  2.5  4
2000-01-01 00:06:00    6  3    3
```

The end goal is to average all columns in the data frame on each index. If there is an easier way than to 'extend' the shorter columns let me know. I would like the resulting table to look like this:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0  
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
2000-01-01 00:03:00    2.8333
2000-01-01 00:04:00    3.6667
2000-01-01 00:05:00    3.8333
2000-01-01 00:06:00    4
```

Much Mahalo :)

EDIT: I have changed the original data that I posted by adding a third column. I realized that my original post did not reflect that I need a solution that works for columns that increases and decreases arbitrarily and is independent of other columns.

Comment: Are the values in the second column always in increasing order? And do you want a constant step size?

Comment: No they are not always increasing, they typically only change by 1 or 2 values, but they decrease and increase. They also never change consistently, so a constant step size would alter the data.

Answer (score 1):

Data `df`

```
                 time  col1  col2
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00     0   0.0
1 2000-01-01 00:01:00     1   1.0
2 2000-01-01 00:02:00     2   2.0
3 2000-01-01 00:03:00     3   3.0
4 2000-01-01 00:04:00     4   NaN
5 2000-01-01 00:05:00     5   NaN
6 2000-01-01 00:06:00     6   NaN
```

Code:

```
# get min/max values in col2
col2_min = df.col2.min()
col2_max = df.col2.max()

# restart col2 with min/max value only,
# and then interpolate values based on col1 values
df.col2 = np.nan
df.loc[df.col1.min(), 'col2'] = col2_min
df.loc[df.col1.max(), 'col2'] = col2_max
df.col2 = df.set_index('col1').col2.interpolate(method='index')
df['col3'] = (df.col1 + df.col2) / 2
```

Output:

```
                 time  col1  col2  col3
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00     0   0.0  0.00
1 2000-01-01 00:01:00     1   0.5  0.75
2 2000-01-01 00:02:00     2   1.0  1.50
3 2000-01-01 00:03:00     3   1.5  2.25
4 2000-01-01 00:04:00     4   2.0  3.00
5 2000-01-01 00:05:00     5   2.5  3.75
6 2000-01-01 00:06:00     6   3.0  4.50
```

I assumed `col2` value is linearly proportional to `col1`, so firstly identifying `min` and `max` values in `col1` as well as `col2` and try to match those. And then interpolate `col2` values based on `col1` values.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I realized that my question left out an important aspect of the problem, the actual data increases and decreases, not just increases consistently. I have updated the question after reading your answer. Thanks again.